# zoom effect on parallax background is not taking effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm on `Wordpress` using `Bridge` theme and I'm wanting to make a zoom effect when the user scrolls over the parallax background I've set up.

Here is my CSS:

```
.parallax {
        /* Set a specific height */

    overflow: hidden;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }

.parallax img{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="fly-over-state" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid  parallax full_screen_section" style="background-image:url(image.png); text-align:center;"><div class=" full_section_inner clearfix"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper"></div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  parallax__plane__text">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Some Text</strong></h3>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong style="font-size: 44px!important;">Some more text</strong></h2>

        </div> 
    </div> </div></div></div><div class="fly-over-text wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  display__on__mobile">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #eaeaf6; font-size: 17px;"><strong>Texty text text</strong></h3>

        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  display__on__mobile">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 22px!important; letter-spacing: 3px; color: #eaeaf6;">Texty text</h3>

        </div> 
    </div> </div></div></div></div></div>
```

And then my JS:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#fly-over-state img").css({
        transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+(scroll/100)+'%, 0) scale('+(100 + scroll/5)/100+')'
    });
});
```

Again, I'm wanting my image to zoom in when I scroll over it, but sadly it does not. For elaboration, see [this tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/zoom-hero-images-scroll), which is what I followed to build it out.

I'm wondering if since I'm on wordpress I missed a div or something like that? My JS file is `zoom.js` and wen I check `Sources` on `Chrome Developer Tools` it's showing up so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: There are several things going wrong here. Your jQuery is targeting **"#fly-over-state img"** for the css transform but there is no img element inside of the **#fly-over-state** div. The image is generated from an inline style background-img on the **#fly-over-state** div. There also is no img inside of the .parallax class referenced in your CSS. Does [this code pen](https://codepen.io/chrisbradshaw/pen/eKXMZm) solve your problem? If not, can you please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, yes this absolutely does solve my problem. Given my HTML, what am I doing wrong that's different than your solution?

Comment: Not too many problems with HTML (I would recommend not setting inline styles however - especially set **background-img** in CSS). In your CSS, everything in **.parallax img** can be deleted. In the JS, everything **translate3d()** under transform can be deleted, and of course set the correct selector **$('.parallax')**. I would use the codepen I posted as a template and start over.

Comment: Thanks so just use .parallax in jquery? Didn’t your code pen have an img within jquery?